# Exit pry session by alias command

Tags: ruby, pry

I wanna exit pry session by `q` instead of `exit!`

Both are not working for me.

```
Pry.commands.alias_command 'q', 'exit!'

Pry.commands.rename_command 'q', 'exit!'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Pry.commands.alias_command :q, "!!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Grych's answer works great for me. Just wanted to point out that the `alias_command` method takes a third argument, which allows you to add a description for the alias:

`Pry.commands.alias_command :q, :exit, 'a helpful and poetic description for exiting from pry'`